# Angular 2 MVC based project with VS 2017 and TFS build server offline (without internet and npm)

Tags: angular, tfs, npm, tfsbuild, offline

The final goal is to set up an Angular 2 app using our infrastructure, so our development team could work with it and it could be delivered to production.

There are a few (or more) topics, that seems to be similar to this, but we couldn't find solutions to some problems we're facing... To be clear, for a last two weeks we've been searching for those solutions, but with no luck.

Hope this discussion will help us and many other.

So far done:

- Got a [angular 2 started kit](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular2-GettingStarted/tree/master/APM%20-%20Start) using a personal computer (our DEV environment is offline) to be able to run npm-install
- Created an MVC project to host the angular 2 app
- Imported the angular 2 starter kit (including node_modules folder) to DEV environment and integrated it into an MVC app

** node_modules folder is not included into the project, but placed manually in the root of it.

Right now there are two main problems we're facing:

- We can't include the node_modules folder (from that specific kit and some others) into the project, as there are build failures right after that. So our team is forced to copy it one from another to place it manually in the root of the project folder (witch is not right).
- The node_modules folders is huge (thousands of files). It is fine for the DEV environment, but it doesn't make sense, that all those files should get to production. There are some topic about Angular CLI, but we didn't find how to implement it into a TFS build server.

We're using:

- VS 2017 as an IDE
- TFS as a source code management
- TFS build server
- We're using TFS for CI/CD as well (branches, automatic builds, semi-automatic deployments)

Questions:

1. We need a angular 2 kit (including node_modules folder) that can be included into TFS project, that won't cause build failures.
2. How to implement angular CLI considering the technologies we're working with?

Comment: What kind of the failures appers if including the node_modules folder into the TFS project?

Comment: @Andy-MSFT Unfortunately it takes ages to include the folder and it freezes VS completely and then crashes it... The failure was because of the package.json of one of the dependencies of one of the modules. Some `.ts` files are required, but they don't appear (there are some topic here on stackoverflow about it). But even if I comment those ones (which may be not a good idea at all), build start to fail because of some mismatch in some module dependency between string and number (didn't find anything about this)... So may this starter kit isn't the best idea for a VS implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly suggest you not rely on TFS Build to restore npm packages. Even when you get that right, it takes long and doesn't deploy the *node_modules* you need to IIS.

Instead, use WebPack to bundle up your node_modules into a bundle.js. Reference this in your projects/scripts folder and check it into source control.

Remove any npm install steps in your build process (it won't be required anymore since you're referencing the bundle.js now).

This will increase your quality (no future package version surprises), and speed up your deployment (no need to download npm packages on each build anymore).

It's fairly quick to get Webpack installed and you'll save your headache.

Comment: I've run into the same issue and I think this piece of advice deserves some credit!